# Batch publishing with childs in Event Handler

Tags: web8.5, event-system

I'm trying to control in which Publications an item is published when I publish in all child Publications.

What I developed is:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<RepositoryLocalObject, PublishEventArgs>(PublshingWithChilds, EventPhases.Initiated);

private void PublshingWithChilds(RepositoryLocalObject item, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
        if (args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeChildPublications)
            {
             ....
            }
}
```

This works fine when I send only one Component or Page to publish.

But if I try to publish a list of Pages or Components from the CME and I select "publish with childs", the first item has:

`args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeChildPublications = true`.

But all the other items that I sent to publish have:

`args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeChildPublications = false`

Is there another variable that contains that I selected "publish in child publications"?

Could I share the value of the first item with the others?

Comment: To clarify, you're saying you are selecting a number of pages and selecting "Publish in child publications" on that whole selection, but the flag is only set on the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with sdl support team and they explained that if I modify the value for args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeChildPublications it affects to all the items sent to publish in the same process.

I had to use ContextVariables to maintain a list of items and publications where the items were published.